# Fabricate a datset to test PCA in Sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, pca

I would like to test my workflow for PCA, to do so I want to create a dataset with lets say 3 features with a set relationship between those features. then apply the PCA and check if the those relationships were captures, what is the most straightforward way to do it in Python ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create samples where two features are independent of each other and a third feature is a linear combination of the other two.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import random

N_SAMPLES = 1000

samples = random((N_SAMPLES, 3))

# Let us suppose that the column `1` will have the dependent feature, the other two being independent

samples[:, 1] = 3 * samples[:, 0] - 2 * samples[:, 2]
```

Now if you run PCA to find two principal components on that sample, the "explained variance" should be equal to 1.

For example:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca2 = PCA(2)
pca2.fit(samples)

assert sum(pca2.explained_variance_ratio_) == 1.0 # this should be true
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I find the relationship when I do the PCA, would the component giving the linear combination are the same as the weight used for he samples?

Comment: No, it is not possible to be sure of that. Depending on the size of your sample the PCA may be implemented in a randomised way, which may find different principal components if those different answers have the same `explained_variance_ratio_`.